# How do I combine two columns in the same table into one?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in one table:

***months*** , ***names***

---

*February* , *Jessica*

*March* , *April*

*April* , *Amanda*

---

And my desired output is:

---

***combined_column***

*February*

*March*

*April*

*Jessica*

*Amanda*

---

I know I will need a *SELECT DISTINCT*, but anything else I try results in output like:

---

***combined_column***

*FebruaryJessica*

*MarchApril*

*AprilAmanda*

---

How can I write my SQL query to get the output I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
Select months from table_name
Union
Select names from table_name
```

Note : Union was used to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But is it also possible to do a count on both columns to show how many times each name/month is recorded, and display it next to the combined column? So that, using this example, April would have a count of 2, and the rest have a count of 1

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
SELECT Months, COUNT(Months) FROM  (
    SELECT months AS Months FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NAMES AS Months FROM table_name
) X 
GROUP BY Months
```